# How many solutions are there to the equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many solutions are there to the equation: $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 =29$ where $x_i > 2$?

The part that I'm confused about is in the solution it says: Since $x_i \ge $ 2, we let $y_i = x_i − 2, y_i \ge 0$. **Is this because $x_i \ge 2$ and we can re-arrange the inequality as $x_i - 2 \ge 0$ and then let $x_i - 2 = y_1$ and then we can re-arrange again to get $x_i$ by itself?** Or did I misunderstand the algebra?

The given solution was:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 =29$
$(y_1+2) + (y_2+2) + (y_3+2) + (y_4+2) + (y_5+2) + (y_6+2) =29$
$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 = 17$

So the solution from here is simply $C(17 + 6 − 1, 17)$.

And all that makes sense to me except for the part that I **bolded** that im not 100% sure about.

Thank you!

Comment: Your understanding is correct except that if you want $x_i > 2$, then $y_i > 0$ and the number of solutions is $\binom{16}{5}$. The given answer is for the number of solutions with $x_i \geq 2$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm just wondering where you got $\dbinom{16}{5}$ shouldn't it be $\dbinom{17}{5}$?

Comment: Put 17 stars in a row. We need to put 5 plus signs in the gaps between them. There are 16 gaps and we can choose 5 in $\binom{16}{5}$ ways.

Comment: Oops got myself confused, thank you so much for the clarification! :)

Comment: Infinitely many ... unless you also specify that all $x_i$ need to be whole numbers